# How to periodically wait one microsecond in java

Tags: java, linux, time

I don't trust the `sleep` and `wait` methods. And I found `select` method in C, but I can not found in java.

Comment: You cannot sleep or wait for one microsecond. Your best bet is to loop for some iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If by “trust” you mean you expect perfect timing with microseconds precision, then you should not be using conventional Java. Nor should you be using conventional operating systems on conventional hardware. Expecting exact scheduling to the microsecond is unreasonable.

To quote the Javadoc for [`Thread#sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long,int)):

> … subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers

If you need such precision, research [real time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).

Comment: I think `sleep` function is not precise enough and is easily disturbed by various signals.